# How can I reset a strategy script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've run a main script yesterday with a pyramiding of 2.
In parallel, I have worked on improving my strategy code, and this morning I had 5 open trades instead of 2 maximum (if I've well understood the fact that `pyramiding=2` means that it is not possible to have more than 2 open trades).

I have closed manually all my open trades in MT4, but I would like to reset my strategy that is still running on tradingview.

How can I reset a strategy script, in order to not to have pending orders, etc.?

Comment: Actually, I've precisions about my issue : I can have more than 2 opened trades in MT4 (desptire pyramiding=2), because some positions are closed by new opened positions by te fact of pyramiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `pyramiding=2` means the maximum number of open trades you can have in the same direction is 2. If on MT4, you have more than 2, your alerts must have been fired more than 2 times.

In order to cancel a pending order, you should use the `strategy.cancel()` command.

```
strategy.cancel(id) → void
```

> ***id (series string)*** A required parameter. The order identifier. It is
> possible to cancel an order by referencing its identifier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Actually, I've precisions about my issue : I'm using Pineconnector. I can have more than 2 opened trades in MT4 (despite pyramiding=2), because some positions are closed by new opened positions because of pyramiding.
In my code, I have only developed alerts on my close conditions, but I haven't coded alerts if positions are closed  by pyramiding. 
I've tried to code a counter that is incremented or decremented with my open and close conditions, but it doesn't work.
Is there an easier way to generate a pineconnector alert if a position is closed by an new one?Thx